# htaccess убрать слово из url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть сайт на php, проблема в том что он зашифрован, и хотелось бы убрать из ссылок слово - search, можно ли это сделать как то с помощью htaccess, и чтобы сайт при этом не завалился?

Пример http://site.ru/search/flats/ сделать http://site.ru/flats/

Comment: Нельзя, раз вы не имеете доступа к коду, который формирует ссылки. .htaccess тут не поможет.

Comment: @Visman поможет, для этих целей используется `mod_substitute`

Comment: @teran , можете подсказать как это реализовать?

Comment: @zoinx2012 добавил ответ, попробуйте, может получится. Но расширение апача надо включить сначала. По крайней мере, ищите примеры по `mod_substitution`

Answer (score 1):

для внесения изменений в сгенерированный контент вам потребуется включить расширение [`mod_substitute`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html). Согласно документации директивы изменения можно вносить как на уровне `Directory` так и в `.htaccess`.

Если необходимо изменить генерацию только `href`-ссылок,
то директива должна выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
 AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
 Substitute "s|http://site.ru/search/|http://site.ru/|ni"
```

в данном случае должна выполняться регистро-независимая замена подстроки без использования регулярных выражений, которая должна заменить все ссылки, начинающиеся с `http://site.ru/search/` на `http://site.ru/` (точнее начало ссылок).

Но надо понимать, что помимо ссылок в html-контенте могут быть и прочие места использования адресов, в т.ч. java-скрипты, различные атрибуты и т.д.

Comment: зы: на практике никогда этого не делал, ответ составлен на основании страницы документации. На полную корректность не претендует.